# SQL JDBTempalate weblogic

Tags: java, spring, weblogic

I am executing SQLs via following code statement.
Application server is weblogic 12c
and `Spring 3.1.1 API` is used.

```
getJdbcTemplate().execute()...
```

I am wondering if `getJdbcTemplate()` returns DB connection itself or a reference to connection pool hosted at weblogic.

And if connection is closed after sql is executed?

Answer (score 0):

If you define the datasource on Weblogic level and you reference that via a JNDI lookup in your spring configuration ==> will return a connection from the pool it was configured on Weblogic.

However with Spring you can configure your own pool without using Weblogic's one.

So depends on how you use it.

Cheers.